# How to define the average of a multivariable function in infinite space?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, average, gaussian

We know that the average of a function $f(x)$ where $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in the interval $[a,b]$ can be computed by
$$
\langle f(x) \rangle =\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)dx.
$$
How should we define the average of a function in an infinite domain, say $[a,+\infty)$ and $(-\infty, \infty)$, given that the limits $\lim_{x \rightarrow \pm \infty} f(x)$ exist? And how do we extend this to functions $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$? Is it, for example, reasonable to say that the average of a function $f(\vec{x})$ is
$$
\langle f(\vec{x}) \rangle = \lim_{L \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{L^n} \int_{-L}^L \int_{-L}^L \dots \int_{-L}^L f(\vec{x})d\vec{x}
$$
? What about choosing another coordinate system, say, a generalized spherical coordinate system instead, and integrate the function in a high-dimensional sphere with the radius approaching infinity? What properties does the function have to fulfill to ensure that all coordinate representations give equal results?

If any illustrative examples are used, I would prefer that a high-dimensional Gaussion function could be taken as an example, which is a perfect example of function that approaches to zero in all directions.

The problem that I am originally dealing with is to calculate the variance of the linear combination of Gaussian functions centered at different locations, which involves evaluating the average of something like this
$$
\sum_{i,j} e^{-[(\vec{x}-\vec{x}_i)^2 + (\vec{x}-\vec{x}_j)^2]/2\sigma^2}
$$
over the entire $\mathbb{R}^n$ space.

Comment: Are you familiar with measure/integration/probability theory?

Comment: The reason we choose $1/(b-a)$ is because that is the 1D volume of the region we are integrating over: $[a,b]$ (compare this to the discrete average).  If we are integrating over some $K$ bounded in $n$-space, then we can similarly compute the average: $$\text{avg}(f) = \frac{1}{\text{Vol}(K)} \int_K f$$ And as your intuition suggests, we can compute the average of a function over all space (if everything is well behaved) as: $$\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{\text{Vol}(tK)} \int_{tK} f$$

Comment: @blamethelag It's been a long time when I last dealt with measure theory but I think I can search when I don't understand something, so please go ahead if you think it's needed for explanation.

Comment: @William How can we prove that this is true for any arbitrary bounded region $K$?

Comment: What do you mean "prove"? In this case (or the more general case given in the answer below), this is how we *define* the average.

Comment: @William I doubt that's a good definition, because if $f\in L^1(\Bbb{R}^n)$, then the limit you write down is always $0$ ($\left|\frac{1}{\text{vol}(tK)}\int_{tK}f\right|\leq \frac{1}{\text{vol}(tK)}\cdot \|f\|_1\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$). SO, averages are really only best defined with respect to probability measures (or with respect to finite measures, provided we divide the measure of the total space... which again is really just the same as a probability measure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on what you mean by "average". If you want an operation on some functional space then you have a lot of possibilities, even if you ask some properties as linearity, continuity etc. The more general construction to my knowledge is
$$
\langle f \rangle = \int_X f d\mathbb P
$$
which is the expectation of $f$ seen as a random variable on a probability space $(X, \mathcal T, \mathbb P)$. What you call "the" average of $f$ is the last construction with the uniform probability on $[a,b]$. It seems natural because it is the only probability measure on $[a,b]$ that is a multiple of the Lebesgue measure, which itself satisfies an intuitive property, but you might want to weight differently your space, for instance with a normal distribution.

Considering your original question, you want to specify your sample of Gaussian variables because the law of the sum of Gaussian variables can vary a lot given the cases. For instance it is not even sure it is Gaussian, so the theoretical computations might be complicated.